# Best way to make a polling thread

Tags: c#

In my application I need a background thread that contacts a server every N seconds...

I made it in this way:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep (10000);
                ...do my stuff...
            }
        });
```

This solution works fine but I need to know if there is a better one. (for example: is Task.Delay(10000) a better solution?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're better off using a BackgroundWorker

Comment: @EdmundCovington BackgroundWorker offers no benefits over Task.Run, but has several problems: You are constructing an entire component that needs disposing, orchestrating asynchronous operations is almost impossible, you get a very limited ability to update the UI through an event. A `System.Threading.Timer` timer easily executes work on a different thread, the `Progress<T>` class allows thread-safe updating of the UI with whatever you want as a payload, Tasks can be awaited, composed and they don't need disposing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use the UI you could use the example of DaveDev, otherwise the example below would also work. If you want to use UI in this example you have to use the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` methods of the controls.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class TimerExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create a timer that signals the delegate to invoke  
        // CheckStatus after one second, and every 1/4 second  
        // thereafter.
        Timer stateTimer = new Timer(CheckStatus);

        // Change the period to every 1/2 second.
        stateTimer.Change(0, 500);

    }

    public static void CheckStatus(Object stateInfo) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I think it is important to know why not to use `Thread.Sleep` in this case. If you use sleep it locks up the thread. If you use a timer then the thread can be used to do other tasks in the meantime.

Comment: Yes that is right, it runs in ThreadPool. Also the code must be reentrant because it can be called before it is finished executing the last loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        _timer.Start();


    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            //do your stuff
        };

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more info: In //do your stuff, is better to usa Thread.Sleep o Task.Delay?

Comment: Nitpicking here, but I'd go with `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` for readability.